# How to delete files/folders with illegal names?

Tags: linux, windows, fat32

How can I delete a set of files that contain illegal characters *including new lines*? The file system is FAT32.

On Windows, besides trying with Explorer, which gave me a 80004005 error, I've tried `rmdir`, `del /F` and [`del "\\?\drive\..."`](https://serverfault.com/questions/95581/delete-file-containing-invalid-characters-in-windows), from Administrator CMD of course.

On a friend's Ubuntu, I've tried `rm -rf`, which has given no results, besides errors of course.

The errors I've been getting from both systems revolve around the illegality of the syntax and no having no permissions. The 80004005 erros come from attempting to delete the parent folder. I've tried to `chmod` the files into complicity but it had no effect.

Curiously enough, attempting to view the files in Ubuntu's Explorer has also resulted in an error:
[image: LS of the folder and an error from Ubuntu's Explorer]

Additionally some of the files seem to contain new lines within their names. Very strange indeed. I don't really understand how this was allowed in the first place.

Is there anything else I could try besides a reformat?

Context: I'm getting into the whole password manager thing, and as part of that, I wanted to have a portable copy of my password manager on my USB stick. As such I've downloaded the portable version, and using WinRAR, I've attempted to unzip it into the USB. Errors occurred, iirc of similar nature, and now we're here.
The broken files only exist within the XSL which as a whole is broken. I'm not sure what WinRAR has done wrong, since initally it was only supposed to be 5 xsl files.
The password manager was KeyPass 2.

Comment: So, it’s a new USB drive that was hosed from the get go. Is there any reason you aren’t simply reformatting it and starting over?

Comment: @Appleoddity Learning experience in case this happens on a system or backup partition.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever corrupted your directory entries probably also corrupted the disc locations, some pointing to outside the partition, with consequent I/O errors.

You need to do a file system repair: try Windows first, but then Ubuntu if it fails.

If all else fails, copy all the other directories, format the disc, then copy back the valid directories; on a system disc you may need to do a clean re-install before copying the files back.

Comment: I've tried `chkdsk /F` with no use. It supposedly couldn't schedule the disk for a repair. Would you know to happen the Ubuntu disk repair tool?

Comment: My friend tried using `mcheck` on it, with no results.

Comment: The usb partition is FAT32 though, as mentioned in the question and tags. @AFH

Comment: @Mox - You're quite right: I came back to this after a break and didn't fully reread the question, thinking I'd remembered enough. I'll delete my irrelevant comment. Thanks.

Comment: I now don't know what to suggest: [`testdisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) on Ubuntu can do some FAT repairs, but I don't know if these will help.